# NodeJs Npm Start works but node index.js doesn't. SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, express

I have an app in NodeJS with Apollo Server, Graphql, etc. I want to use PM2 to have my index like a service so, when I close the console It dont stop.

When I execute npm start the server starts perfect. This is my start in package.json

**"start": "nodemon ./index.js --exec babel-node -e js",**

If I execute node index.js then this error appears.

```
/home/ubuntu/react/desafio/servidor/index.js:1
import express from 'express';
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

this is my index.js code

```
 import express from 'express';
    import { ApolloServer, AuthenticationError } from 'apollo-server-express';
    import { typeDefs } from './data/schema';
    import { resolvers } from './data/resolvers';
    import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
    import dotenv from 'dotenv';
    import db from "./models";

    dotenv.config({path:'variables.env'});

    const cors = require('cors');
    const app = express();
    // enable cors

     // app.use(cors());
    const addToken = async (req) =>{

    }
    const server=  new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers
    });

    server.applyMiddleware({app});
    app.listen({port:9000},()=> console.log(`Server Corriendo http://localhost:9000${server.graphqlPath}`));
```

what Im doing wrong?

Comment: What version of node are you using? https://2ality.com/2019/04/nodejs-esm-impl.html#using-es-modules-on-node.js

Comment: Did you install node packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**node index.js** will throw an error because your code is in **ES6**, to successfully run your code you will  have to run it with babel-node which will compile it to **ES5**. babel-node comes with the babel-cli which you have to install.

**" ./index.js --exec babel-node -e js"** exactly does this which is to compile **ES6** to **ES5**

> Babel helps to turn our codes from ES6 to ES5. There are some ES6
>   features that our browsers and node are yet to understand, and older
>   browsers do not understand ES6 codes, so we use babel to compile our
>   code to ES5 so that both old browsers and new browsers can understand.

Answer (score 0):

**While import is indeed part of ES6, it is unfortunately not yet supported in NodeJS by default, and has only very recently landed support in browsers.**
check this [node import vs require](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/53)
in [node 9](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) ** it is enabled behind a flag, and uses the .mjs extension**

```
node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs
```

you can use require statements:

```
const express = require("express");
```

**If you really want to use new ES6/7 features in NodeJS, you can compile it using Babel**